# MySql. One column, two different data types, multiple where query

Tags: mysql

I have got a mysql table structure:

```
uid     company     value
```

Description:
uid -> unical id
company -> four letters code of company ie. `AAAA`, `BIEW`
value -> is a code of two different type of data: country or region, where:
country: `"/[0-9]+\-/"`, ie. *49-*, character at the end `-` means this is a region value
region: `"/[0-9]+\_[0-9]+/"`, ie. *49_002* , *49_4*, character `_` means this is a country value

Now I want to SELECT all records WHICH:

- has a multiple company definitions, ie. `AAAA' OR 'BIEW'`
- has a multiple country definitions, ie. `'49-' OR '5698-'`
- first of countries above has specified region. I wan to search `49_01` only but not `49_03` and `49_965`, which also "belongs" to `49-` country
- second of countries `'5698-'` don't have specified regions and should return only records where `value='5698-'`

The `AAAA` company has 'filter' that specify country/region records but `BIEW` has not any specified country/region values. The MYSQL query don't work properly:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (company='AAAA' OR company='BIEW') AND (value='5698-' OR value='49_01')
```

Comment: Nothing wrong in storing two datatypes in one column. But everything would be more elegant (and easier btw) if you had another table(s) to store regions and countries

Comment: I can work only at this table, I have only access to this table so if there is another tables makes database more elegant that isn't part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE tourOP = 'AAAA' AND (val = '5698-' OR val = '49_01') OR tourOP = 'BIEW'
```